# My program created so many proccesses and crashed the OS, how to solve it?

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, diskspace

I create the following program which needs to "play ping pong" between a parent process and its child process.

Even while working on it, while compiling, I noticed that my PC starts to work harder and harder but I didn't really think it's a problem.

In the end I found myself crashing my Linux, creating lots of different processes that slow down the PC and also create a lot temp/logs file and cause my disk to have 200MB of free space instead of 35GB .

How can I fix those problems?

1. How can I stop my program from creating a lot of different processes?
2. How can I clean up my logs directory? I tried
   `sudo apt autoremove` and `autoclean` and delete all `.gz` files in the `/var/log` directory.

But it did not help. My disk space still stands on free 200MB and a `/var/log` directory of almost 40GB for some reason.

I don't want to remove necessary files that located in the `/var/log` directory so I'm not removing the entire directory.

Why did my program even created so many temp or logs file?

Thanks.

```
 /******************************** Header Files ********************************/
    
    #define _GNU_SOURCE 
    
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <stdio.h>      /*  printf                          */
    #include <stdlib.h>     /*  exit                            */
    #include <unistd.h>     /*  fork, getpid, sleep             */
    
    /**************************** Forward Declarations ****************************/
    
    /*  exits the program with the given 'ret status' if 'is_bad' is true       */
    void ExitIfBad(int is_bad, char *msg_to_print, int ret_stat);
    
    void handle_siguser1(int signal_id);
    
    void handle_siguser2(int signal_id);
    
    enum {CHILD = 0};
    
    static int is_parent_turn = 1;
    
    /************************* Functions  Implementations *************************/
    int main()
    {
        /*  create a child process  */
        pid_t pid = fork();
        
        ExitIfBad(pid < 0, "Error: Could not create a process\n", 1);
        
        signal(SIGUSR1, handle_siguser1);
        signal(SIGUSR2, handle_siguser2);
        
        /*  returned to the newly created child process. */
        if (CHILD == pid)
        {   
            while (1)
            {
                /*  pause child process and let parent to begin */
                sleep(2);
                
                kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
                
            }
        }
            
        /* returned to parent */
        else
        {   
            while (1)
            {
                kill(getpid(), SIGUSR1);
            }
        }
            
        return 0;   
    }
    /******************************************************************************/
    void handle_siguser1(int signum)
    {
        if (is_parent_turn)
        {
            printf("\n\nPING\n\n");
            is_parent_turn = 0;
        }
        
        else
        {
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
    /******************************************************************************/
    void handle_siguser2(int signum)
    {
        if (!is_parent_turn)
        {
            printf("\n\nPONG\n\n");
            is_parent_turn = 1;
        }
        
        else
        {
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
    /******************************************************************************/
    void ExitIfBad(int is_bad, char *msg_to_print, int ret_stat)
    {
        if (is_bad)
        {
            puts(msg_to_print);
            exit(ret_stat);
        }
    }
    /******************************************************************************/
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: While `sleep` is marked as signal-safe, please don't sleep inside a signal handler, as they should generally be quick. On the other hand `printf` is ***not*** signal-safe. See [the `signal-safety` manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude which means the `printf` might cause a memory flood??

Comment: but what about all the 40GB unknown data which was added to the `/var/log` directory, what i'm supposed to do with it? How can I remove it without harming the important system files?

Comment: Have you *checked* the log files to see what's taking so much space? And the code you show can't fork-bomb your system like the `ps` output make it look like. Unless there's something somewhere which you forgot to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude nope, there is no other thing. this is the whole program. only this code. and yes, I check the `var/log` directory and found out a file called `syslog` is 30GB. other than that, the rest seems normal.

Comment: exactly like you said, my code bascially can't fork-bomb my system because `fork` isn't in a loop. so how did it happen?

Comment: Try running `tail -100 /var/log/syslog` to see the last 100 entries in it. Do any of them seem related to your program?

Comment: Talking about `is_parent_turn`, there's no definition of it only an assignment in the global scope which isn't allowed. So this isn't a proper [mcve]. Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the *full* and *complete* code you build and run (including header files includes)

Comment: Oh, and try to remove the executable program, and all object files (if there are any), and then rebuild the program from the source you show.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edited the question and supplied the **FULL**  code including the header files and everything. It compiles and runs and does print `PING` and also `PONG` and changes `is_parent_turn` when needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to run `tail -100` as you told me and found nothing that is related to my program there.  Maybe because the last time I ran my program was about 3-4 hours ago, and since then i'm scared to do that and also been through other apps like browser and discord.

Comment: Okay, then you need to get further back in the log file, to when you last ran your program. Use `grep` to "filter" out roughly and pipe it into `less` so you can go through the log.

Comment: sorry, it was my bad while copying it. It does set it to zero when it prints `PING`. 
This is should be a very simple and basic program that "plays" ping pong between 2 processes. IDK what went wrong and where and why did it crash my entire OS.

Comment: Reboot, rebuild. and rerun. And make sure that you rebuild the code you show us in this question, and that you run the program you just build from that code. If it still bombs your system, please tell us how you build the program, and how you run it. To protect yourself, you might want to do some research about *containers* and *virtual machines*.

Comment: Is the program running recursively? I once had a very similar issue. My windows system almost crashed. Then I realized that I am calling the name of the same name of the program through `system().` Make sure that no recursion occurs in your code.